# If user doesn't change date, set variable

Tags: android

If the user clicks on a button, I set myVar = true, then show a date picker dialog. In the date set listener, onDateSet, I check to see if myVar = true. If so, I do a little extra then set myVar = false.

Problem is, if somebody clicks the button then doesn't continue to set a date. They click back or they click cancel... myVar still = true. If they fail to change the date, I need myVar = false. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: I'm using the code from the tutorial at: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

Comment: Right above showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);, I set myVar = true. Right above updateDisplay(); in the onDateSetListener, I check... if myVar = true { do this, set myVar = false }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just create a second variable like boolean cancelled = false; Set it to true when a date is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a [CancelListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html) to the dialog, using [setOnCancelListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnCancelListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29)

Hope this helps,

Phil